# call class $this from external function

Tags: php

inside a template php files, i have hundreds of such code:

```
echo str_replace('x','y', $this->load1->view('something'));
```

i have replaced that line everywhere, with code:

`echo blabla();`

and placed a function in my core library:

```
function blabla(){ 
   return str_replace('x','y', $GLOBALS['this']->load1->view('something'));
}
```

but it triggers error: `Fatal error...`

Comment: If you are using `$this`, you are probably already inside a function (called a _method_ when it's in a class - which doesn't require the use of `global`), but if you are not inside a class at all, `$this` should **not** work.

Comment: where is `function blabla()` located? is it in the class you are using `$this` in?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Also you should probably read this. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: You can't have a `global $this` because `$this` is, by its very nature, **never** global.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, `$this` refers to the current object. For Example:

```
class MyClass {
    protected $attribute;

    public function method() {
        $this->attribute;
    }

    public static function staticMethod() {
      //$this is not available here because of the static context!
    }
}
```

`$this` is used inside the `MyClass`.

**For more details**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

Re: your edited question, `$this` only exists within the class.

You have two options:

```
function blabla($something){ 
   str_replace('x','y', $something);
}

blablah($this->load1->view('something'));
```

Or, put `function blabla() {` inside the class, and drop the `global $this` line.